# Using coroutines in a right way

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mvp

I am implementing the coroutine for first time. I am following MVP pattern for a simple login app. Here is my code flow -

The login button clicked will follow this direction -

LoginFragment -> LoginPresenter -> Repository -> APIRepository -> RetrofitInterface

The login response will follow this direction -

RetrofitInterface  -> APIRepository  -> Repository  -> LoginPresenter -> LoginFragment

Here is the code -

RetrofitInterface.kt

```
@POST("login")
    fun loginAPI(@Body loginRequest: LoginRequest): Deferred<LoginResponse>?
```

Here is my Result.kt

```
sealed class Result<out T : Any> {

    class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()

    class Error(val exception: Throwable, val message: String = exception.localizedMessage) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

APIRepository.kt

```
override suspend fun loginAPICall(loginRequest: LoginRequest) : Result<LoginResponse>? {
        try {
            val loginResponse = apiInterface?.loginAPI(loginRequest)?.await()
            return Result.Success<LoginResponse>(loginResponse!!)
        } catch (e : HttpException) {
            return Result.Error(e)
        } catch (e : Throwable) {
            return Result.Error(e)
        }
    }
```

Repository.kt

```
override suspend fun loginUser(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Result<LoginResponse> {
        if (isInternetPresent(context)) {
            val result = apiRepositoryInterface?.loginAPICall(loginRequest)
            if (result is Result.Success<LoginResponse>) {
                val loginData = result.data
                cache?.storeData(loginData)
            }
            return result!!
        } else {
            return Result.Error(Exception())
        }
    }
```

How do I launch a coroutine now in my presenter? I need to execute this API call on a background thread and publish the results on UI thread?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to launch a coroutine in a **Presenter** using local scope and injected `CoroutineContext` to be able to change it, for example in Unit Tests:

```
class Presenter(
    private val repo: Repository,
    private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main
) : CoroutineScope { // creating local scope

    private var job: Job = Job() // or SupervisorJob() - children of a supervisor job can fail independently of each other

    // To use Dispatchers.Main (CoroutineDispatcher - runs and schedules coroutines) 
    // in Android add dependency: implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = uiContext + job

    fun detachView() {
        // cancel the job when view is detached
        job.cancel()
    }

    fun login(request: LoginRequest) = launch { // launching a coroutine
        val result = repo.loginUser(request) // calling 'loginUser' function will not block the Main Thread, it suspends the coroutine

        //use result, update UI
        when (result) {
            is Success<LoginResponse> -> { /* update UI when login success */ } 
            is Error -> { /* update UI when login error */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my login fun of presenter, I do repository.loginUser(request). But it shows me error on loginUser(request) saying suspend function must be called from another suspend function or a coroutine although in my repository loginUser(request) is a suspend function.

Comment: Did you add `launch` builder to your function in Presenter?  `fun login(request: LoginRequest) = launch {...}`

Comment: Strange, It shouldn't show an error, because you are calling that function in a coroutine, using `launch`

Comment: Yes I don't understand this as well

Comment: Is `launch`, you are using, an extension function on `CoroutineScope`?

Comment: Also as per documentation, if the coroutine builder specifies async then it returns a reference as a deferred object. Since I return here a deferred object from my retrofit interface, where should I use async? Also is it right to use Dispatchers.main when we are doing a network operation. Should we not use dispatchers.io?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186647/discussion-between-sergey-and-alessandra-maria).

Comment: You should definitely use SupervisorJob not job. Otherwise if you launch another separate job, i.e. getUser and it fails, it can fail your login also.

Comment: @Sergey I have implemented this, I need to stop the job in onStop and resume it again. But after using job.cancel in onStop the coroutines scope is not launching again.

Answer (score 5):

you can use  coroutine in this way

```
  private var parentJob = Job()

    private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Main

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)



 scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

     // your api call 

 }
```

you can  call `parentJob.cancel()` to cancel the job or call it in onClear of ViewModel

Comment: Why dispatchers.io? As per the documentation, the suspend is already a non blocking thread function and I need to observe the results on Ui. So it should be dispatchers.main right? Please correct me if I am wrong. It's also new to me